# Nginx, fastapi and streamlit in docker - reverse proxy does not work for streamlit

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, nginx-reverse-proxy, streamlit

i want to use docker to containerize nginx, fastapi and 2 streamlit apps. All 3 apps (fastapi, 2streamlit apps) do not interact with each other. Nginx should work as reverse-proxy for the 3 apps.
For fastapi it is working. I can send rest-api requests to http://ip:80/twxservices .
"twxservices" as endpoint is added in the app.py file and not in the nginxconfig.

The streamlit apps are not reachable through this http://ip:80/stream1 and http://ip:80/stream2 I get the error: 404: Not found

Thanks in advance for your help. Find below the filestructures and the config files.
This is the filestructure and how the reverse-proxy should work:

[image]
[image]

docker-compose file:

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./nginxfolder
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: web
   
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - my-network
    depends_on:
      - app

  app:
    build:
      context: ./twxservicesfolder
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
 
    networks:
      - my-network
      
  spectrum:
    build:
      context: ./spectrumfolder
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: spectrum

    networks:
      - my-network
      
  dgraph:
    build:
      context: ./dgraphfolder
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: dgraph

    networks:
      - my-network
       
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

nginx config (default.conf):

```
upstream fastapi-backend {
    server app:8000;
}



    server {
        listen 80;
     

        location /  {
            proxy_pass http://fastapi-backend;
            
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            
       
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            client_body_buffer_size 100M;
            client_max_body_size 100M;
        }
        
        location /stream1 {
            proxy_pass http://spectrum:8501/stream1;
        }
        location ^~ /stream1/static {
            proxy_pass http://spectrum:8501/stream1/static/;
        }
        location ^~ /stream1/healthz {
            proxy_pass http://spectrum:8501/stream1/healthz;
        }
        location ^~ /stream1/vendor {
            proxy_pass http://spectrum:8501/stream1/vendor;
        }
        location /stream1/spectrum {
            proxy_pass http://spectrum:8501/stream1/spectrum;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }
        
        location /stream2 {
            proxy_pass http://dgraph:8503/stream2;
        }
        location ^~ /stream2/static {
            proxy_pass http://dgraph:8503/stream2/static/;
        }
        location ^~ /stream2/healthz {
            proxy_pass http://dgraph:8503/stream2/healthz;
        }
        location ^~ /stream2/vendor {
            proxy_pass http://dgraph:8503/stream2/vendor;
        }
        location /stream2/dgraph {
            proxy_pass http://dgraph:8503/stream2/dgraph;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }

    }
```

Dockerfile nginx container:

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Dockerfile streamlit app dgraph container:

```
FROM python:3.8

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8503
COPY app2.py /var/dashboard/app2.py
CMD streamlit run /var/dashboard/app2.py --server.address="0.0.0.0"  --server.port="8503"
```

Dockerfile streamlit app spectrum container:

```
FROM python:3.8

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8501
COPY app1.py /var/dashboard/app1.py
CMD streamlit run /var/dashboard/app1.py --server.address="0.0.0.0" --server.port="8501"
```

Dockerfile fastapi app twxservices container:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn","app:app","--proxy-headers","--host","0.0.0.0","--forwarded-allow-ips","*"]
```

Comment: maybe `location /` should be as last rule.

Comment: do you know why that should be?

Comment: I'm not sure if it has to be last but many tools (i.e.`virtual_host` in `Apache`, `routing` in `Flask` and `Django`) get first matching location/routing. I'm not sure if `location /` compare as `if / == http://ip:80/stream2:` or `if / in http://ip:80/stream2:` but method with `in` can match all URLs and also `http://ip:80/stream1` and `http://ip:80/stream2` can match to `location /` and it may run wrong application. I would add the shortest `location` as the last. And the longest at the beginning.

Comment: I tried this and moved the location /  of fastapi to the end but it has not helped. Still get the error 404: Not found

Comment: can you connect directly `http://spectrum:8501/stream1` ? Maybe it should be without `stream1` - `http://spectrum:8501/`

Comment: Hi i made it now to work. It is important to paste in the dockerfile of the streamlitcontainer the basepath argument.  E.g. --server.baseUrlPath="spectrum" Then in nginx config it is enough when using following:   `location /spectrum {
   proxy_pass http://spectrum1:8501/spectrum;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   proxy_read_timeout 86400`

Comment: you could write it as answer with detailed description- it will be more readable and maybe it will help other people. And you can mark your answer as accepted, and few minutes later you can upvote your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I made it work with these nginx config

```
    location /spectrum {
            proxy_pass http://spectrum1:8501/spectrum;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }
```

and this Dockerfile config for the streamlit app:

```
FROM python:3.8
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8501
COPY app1.py /var/dashboard/app1.py
CMD streamlit run /var/dashboard/app1.py --server.address="0.0.0.0" --server.port="8501" --server.baseUrlPath="spectrum" --server.enableCORS=false --server.enableXsrfProtection=false
```